# How to use angular bootstrap ui pagination for table?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use [angular-botstrap-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) in my application. But I don't know how I can build pagination.

Let's say I have 100 records in table and I want to fetch 10 results in table row. By using ng-repeat I am getting 100 rows but I want to limit them using pagination. How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this in using the array function slice

```
ng-repeat="row in queryResult.rows.slice(((currentPage-1)*10), ((currentPage)*10))"
```

I have written a blog post about my ingenious solution [here](http://mylifewithjava.blogspot.no/2014/03/a-simple-way-of-doing-pagination-with.html)